# OpenCL built-in function 'select'

Tags: opencl

It's not clear for me what is a purpose of built-in OpenCL function `select`. Can somebody, please, clarify?

From OpenCL specification:

> function *select(gentype a, gentype b, igentype c)*
>
> returns: **for each component of a vector type, result[i] = if MSB of c[i] is set ? b[i] : a[i].**

What is a MSB in this case? I know that MSB stands for *most significant bit*, but I have no idea how it's related to this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OpenCL `select` is to select elements from a pair of vectors `(a, b)`, based on the truth value of a condition vector (`c`), returning a new vector composed of elements from the vectors `a` and `b`.

The MSB (most significant bit) is mentioned here, because the truth value of a vector element is defined to be `-1` and the MSB should therefore be set (as the sign bit):

```c
a = {1 , 2}  // Pseudocode for select operands
b = {3 , 4}
c = {0 ,-1}
r = {1 , 4}  // The result r contains some of a and b
```

Comment: Note that the parameter order is *completely* backwards. If you want to do something like `a > b ? a : b`, then you write `select(b, a, a > b);`. Very stupid. What were they thinking?!

Comment: You could look at it as "if the condition is 0 return argument 0; if the condition is 1 return argument 1". Maybe not so stupid, unlike plenty of other things in OpenCL.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very useful operator which does the same job as what a conditional expression does in C.  However, conditional expression often compiles to a conditional branch which cause warp/wavefront divergence. The 'select' usually generates a predicated expression - kind of like CMOV on x86 or blend_ps in SSE.

Answer (score 1):

I have found 2 basic patterns of using `select`: scalar case and vector case.
Scalar case is pretty straightforward:

`if (a > 0.0f) b = 0.3f;`

is equivalent to

`b = select(b, 0.3f, isgreater(a, 0.0f));`

If wanted to deal with vectors, i.e. obtain a vector result from `select` everything became a bit more complicated:

`if (a > 0.0f) b = (float2)(0.3f, 0.4f);`

is equivalent to

`b = select(b, (float2)(0.3f, 0.4f), (int2)(isgreater(a, 0.0f) << 31));`

That bit-wise shift needed to make LSB result of comparison operator to be MSB to conform `select` specification. Casting to `int2` ensures that all components will take their positions in result.

Concluding remark is that using snippets above helps more to understand usage of `select` rather then thinking of equivalence with C ternary operator `?:`.