# Removing branches when setting local variables

Tags: opencl

Which code is more efficient:

Routine A

```
 local int a[5];
 bool condition;
 ...
 a[0] = 0;
 if (condition) {
      a[0] = 1;
 }
```

or Routine B

```
 local int a[5];
 bool condition;
 ....
 a[0] = 0;
 a[0] = select(a[0], 1, condition);
```

The second listing removes the branch, but the select statement may access local memory twice, if condition is false. Hopefully, the compiler would put in a no-op if condition is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the low level code and the target machine there's a compiler, that and the target machine the compiler is compiling for would ultimately determine the assembly code to be generated.

For instance you can't say things like 'removing the if statement gets rid of the branch', what if the compiler decided to use a compare and set instruction instead of a compare branch followed by move?

If the condition is always false the code will be considered dead code and the compiler may decide to put nothing instead of a no-op.

If you manage to generate the assembly code corresponding for Routine A and Routine B and get a table for the instruction costs for the target machine only then you'd be able to talk about machine code efficiency. Compilers usually have such tables embedded in them to try and choose the most suitable combinations of instructions.

select looks like it's designed for vectors instead of just single values. Most likely so it can use SIMP instructions which operate on arrays rather than just single values like what we have at hand. See [OpenCL built-in function 'select'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635706/opencl-built-in-function-select)